# How to create a wsdl file in Visual studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, wsdl

I need to create a wsdl file to provide it to a third party. I do not have my web service implemented yet. All I have is a document that tells what operations the web service will support and the input and the return (output) parameters for each operation. I need to create a wsdl before implementing the service. Any ideas on how to approach this? Are there any tools that allow to create wsdls manually? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to create a WSDL is let VS create it for you. This can easily be done when creating a WS Application.

So, If you already ***need*** to create the interfaces (to pass them to the 3rd party) but just not the implementation - [Create the webservice itself](http://a1ashiish-csharp.blogspot.com/2012/01/cnet-how-to-create-web-service-in-cnet.html#.UNR8k3fzwZ0) (more specifically the interfaces) but instead of implementing, throw a `NotImplementedException` in all of them.

You can then run the WebService, have it generate the correct WSDL for you (which you can pass to the 3rd party) and all you have left is to *implement* the methods at your free time.